# Convert multiple DataFrames to numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to convert 5 dataframes to numpy arrays in a loop.

```
df = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

for index, x in enumerate(df):
  x = x.to_numpy()
```

`print(type(df3))`  still gives me pandas DataFrame as the output.

Comment: sorry your code does not make sense. you iterate through an array name, df. and then what do you do with index and x?

Comment: I'd recommend reading some [introductory documentation](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) first. Understanding variables and scopes can be tricky in the beginning, and jumping straight to pandas  without having these concepts well-absorbed might not be the best idea ;)

Comment: `np.array([x.to_numpy() for x in df])`

Comment: there are 5 DataFrames. I want to convert each of them to an numpy array in one loop and save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dose not save into the environment

```
for index, x in enumerate(df):
  df[index] = x.to_numpy()
```

Then you do

```
df[0]
```

Comment: is there a way to convert df1, df2, df3 DataFrames to arrays? Your method works as well, but I have to call them from the list df now